# libcunit.so.1 missing after install of CUnit-2.1-2-src.tar.bz2

Tags: postgresql, postgis, glibc, cunit

This is the only tar on the site.. no help online.. Is there some parameter I missed? where do I get this lib?

Answer (score 1):

nm ..was in /usr/local/lib